# Is this a valid definition for prime numbers? $\mathbb P = \{ 2,3,6k \pm 1 = p|k,m,n \in \mathbb N,p \ne (6m \pm 1)(6n \pm 1)\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is this a valid definition for prime numbers?
$$\mathbb P = \{ 2,3,6k \pm 1 = p\mid k,m,n \in \mathbb N,p \ne (6m \pm 1)(6n \pm 1)\}$$

This is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-h3aGR412qm93Kjy1VdS7uTbRa5uHGZ3AviqoyFLdtk/edit) to a google spreadsheet in which you can see a table for $6k+1$ and $6k-1$ for $k$ from $1$ to $100$ (prime numbers to $601$). The highlighted numbers are composite and can be written as $(6m \pm 1)(6n \pm 1)$.

If yes, has anyone seen this definition anywhere?

Comment: $30$ isn't prime.

Comment: @fleablood $30\neq 6k\pm 1$

Comment: Any divisor of a number of the form $6n \pm 1$ is also a number of the same form (but perhaps, with a different sign in the middle).

Comment: The exact formulation might be novel, but all of the ideas contained therein are common knowledge.

Comment: It would have been easier to write $\{ p=2,2k+1 \mid p\not = (2m+1)(2n+1) \} $. Your formulation is valid, but I wouldn't say it is very useful. All it's saying are primes above $3$ are of the form $6k \pm 1$ and doesn't have non-trivial factors (which come from the definition). You could do the same thing by adding $5$ and some extra conditions and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better definition :

$\mathbb{P} = \lbrace k \in \mathbb{N} - \lbrace 1 \rbrace \mid \nexists \space n \in\mathbb{N} - \lbrace 1 , k\rbrace : n \mid k \rbrace $ 
As you can see, the definition itself implies that the set will contain primes. Your definition is also correct, but you know what it means when a number is prime, or if primes have a generic form, or anything of that sort, so it's you who can define the set of primes as per your understanding. As @RoddyMacPhee says in his answer, you can define the same thing in different ways. For example, you can define $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}^+$) as $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{Z} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace | {{|x|}\over{x}} \neq -1 \rbrace$, or you can define it as the sequence $\lbrace a_i | a_1 = 1, a_n = a_{n-1} + 1 \rbrace_{i=1}^{\infty}$ or any other way possible. The only thing you need to mind is that the verbal definition - i.e., the axiomatic definition -  should not be violated. For instance, if you defined the set of natural numbers as a sequence as  $\lbrace a_i | a_1 = 1, a_n = a_{n-1} + 0.5 \rbrace_{i=1}^{\infty}$, your set will be against the axiomatic definition.

As for your second part of the question (whether we have ever seen such a definition), well, I have never seen such a definition though. I have only taken them definition for primes that I have written in my answer as the primary and most implicit definition of the set of prime numbers.